TypeError: "Text must be a string when stream is False" using ElevenLabs `generate` function in Python
I'm working on a Python script that transcribes audio using OpenAI's Whisper API, translates the text to French using DeepL, and then generates speech from the translated text using the ElevenLabs API. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to generate the audio with ElevenLabs.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
import os
from openai import OpenAI
import deepl
from elevenlabs import set_api_key, generate, save

# Set API keys (using environment variables for security)
translator = deepl.Translator(os.environ.get("DEEPL_API_KEY"))
set_api_key(os.environ.get("ELEVENLABS_API_KEY"))
o_client = OpenAI(
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
)

# Open audio file and transcribe
audio_file = open("speech.mp3", "rb")
transcript = o_client.audio.transcriptions.create(
    file=audio_file,
    model="whisper-1",
    response_format="verbose_json",
    timestamp_granularities=["segment"]
)

segments = transcript.segments

for segment in segments:
    segment_text = segment.text
    # Translate text to French
    segment_text_translated = translator.translate_text(segment_text, target_lang="FR").text
    print(type(segment_text_translated))  # Outputs: <class 'str'>
    print(f"Translated text: '{segment_text_translated}'")
    # Generate audio from translated text
    audio = generate(
        text=segment_text_translated,
        voice="Rachel",
        model="eleven_multilingual_v2"
    )
    save(audio, f"segment_{segment.id}.mp3")

And here's the error I'm receiving:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate.py", line 29, in <module>
    audio = generate(
  File "/path/to/elevenlabs/client.py", line 224, in generate
    raise ApiError(body="Text must be a string when stream is False.")
elevenlabs.core.api_error.ApiError: status_code: None, body: Text must be a string when stream is False.

What I've Tried:

Ensured that segment_text_translated is a string by accessing the .text attribute.
Printed type(segment_text_translated) to confirm it's a string.
Used encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8') on the translated text.
Updated the elevenlabs package to the latest version.
Tested the generate function with a hardcoded string, which works fine.

Additional Information:

Python Version: 3.10
Packages and Versions:

openai==0.27.8
deepl==1.6.0
elevenlabs==0.2.14


Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04

Question:
Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the same error. It seems that segment_text_translated is a string, so I'm not sure why the error persists. How can I resolve the "Text must be a string when stream is False" error when using the ElevenLabs generate function with translated text?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I notice you're in a for loop iterating through segments.  Is it possible some of the segments are returning None?

Tim's comment above might be the cause....do put a valid str check before generate
